# Help Window using StatET in Eclipse

Tags: r, eclipse-plugin

I have been getting into R recently and have been using the StatET plugin for Eclipse.  When I search for help, it prints the 'contents' of the help to the console.  I am hoping to have the help open up in a new window, similar to what happens when in R itself.  I am hoping this is just a setting.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

- Brock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to recall that I had a similar problem when I upgraded R and StatET.
Perhaps adding the following line to "RProfile.site" will help. (note RProfile.site for me is currently located in "C:\Program Files\R-2.11.1\etc")

```
options(help_type="html")
```